# Get the value of variable

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am making project for an online examination system.
Project is running successfully. The problem is that at the end user gets whatever marks that should be entered into database.

That I cannot do.

My code is as below.

```
String UserName = request.getParameter("UserName");
String q = "insert into Data (UserName,MARKS) values("+UserName+" , "+count+")";
System.out.println(q);
```

Here, count is the variable in that the marks are stored.

I have printed query. From that I can say that I am getting the value of count variable but I cannot get the value of USERNAME entered by user.

Comment: `request.getParameter("UserName");` UserName is the name of your input type? Can you show the code where you defined UserName input type or corresponding html object?

Answer (score 0):

check parameter 'UserName' is correct or not.

Or

`UserName` can be stored as session value after that you can retrieve.

```
 String userName = request.getParameter("txtUserName");

session.setAttribute("userName", userName);
String manager = session.getAttribute("userName");
```

Comment: action="Rules.jsp" id="mymodal">
    UserName:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" class="input-large"
     placeholder="UserName" name="UserName" id="UserName"><br />
    Password:<input type="password" class="input-large"
     placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password"><br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Sign in</button>

Comment: when you click on sign in button you can test the input value what are entering.

Comment: actually this everything works properly.. but the marks user gets that i want to add in database table. that base table has only 2 fields. that marks and username. but data is not inserting. The data on clicking submit button is inserting but at last marks are not inserting. my code is as below for that. Is it ok or not??            String str = (String)session.getAttribute("UserName");
  String q = "insert into Data (UserName, Marks) values ('"+str+"' , "+count+")";
  System.out.println(q);