# Inserting data into database

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am making a project on an online examination system. everything is working properly in this but I am facing one problem. The user first makes an account by entering username, password, phone etc.. Then the data will be inserted into the database and the exam will be started. It is working properly. But when the user completes the exam I want to add marks into the database with the username. For that I have a table called DATA in the database. I have made a session for username and trying to get an attribute of that usernamr but I am not able to add data into database.

My code is as below for that:

```
String str = (String)session.getAttribute("UserName");
String q = "insert into Data (UserName, Marks) values ('"+str+"' , "+count+")";
System.out.println(q);
```

Comment: First read about `JDBC`.

Comment: What do you do with your q variable after printing it out on the console? What's the value of count variable? Can you post more code? If this is all your code it won't insert nothing in the DB as you state.

Comment: I have connector class in my project that includes all JDBC related code.

Comment: This is the code only for inserting marks into database not to insert whole user data into database.  Here, count is the variable in which user's marks are stored

Comment: I have printed variable q to only check weather query is made properly or not??

Comment: Learn to use `PreparedStatement`s.

Comment: What **exactly** does 'I am not able to add data into database' mean? Your code does not even show any attempt to insert the tuple into a database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the value of variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128157/get-the-value-of-variable)

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this in your code but before that Learn about [JDBC](http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/).

```
Connection con = null;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String db = "jdbctutorial";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, "root", "root");
    try {
        String str = (String)session.getAttribute("UserName");
        String q =
            "insert into Data (UserName, Marks) values ('" + str +
            "' , " + count + ")";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        int val = st.executeUpdate(q);
        System.out.println("Marks added.");
    } catch (SQLException s) {
        System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
    }

}
```

You can also use `PreparedStatement` which is more secure than the `Statement` and also better in performance.

```
  String sql = "INSERT into Data VALUES(?,?)";
  PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  prest.setString(1, str);
  prest.setInt(2, count);
  ps.executeUpdate();
  System.out.println("Marks added.");
  con.close();
```

Comment: I'm rather surprised you didn't advocate the use of a `PreparedStatement`!

Comment: @adarshr i did not use the PreparedStatement as by the question i feel he is a very beginner and in his code he has written a query.So my aim was to make him understand using  most of his code. But now you have told i will edit my answer and add the PreparedStatement part.

Comment: Sure. I feel `PreparedStatement` is one of the fundamentals that even beginners should be aware of. If not in Day 1, at least in Day 2 of their lessons.